Require Module not working in NEXT 14 when trying to get the file data through a script
The following code is a part of a script I am running for certain task. I am using NEXT14 with app router.
            console.log(
              "SEARCH",
              new_path === "../docs/content.mdx"
            );

            const content =
              require("../docs/content.mdx").Data;

            const contentDynamic = require(new_path).Data;

            console.log("CONTENT", content, contentDynamic);

Here, the output of the search is provided as `true`. Thus both the paths are equal. But the content is loaded successfully and contentdynamic throws an error of module not found.

Data is exported perfectly

MDX is also setup accurately.

It is not an error related to mdx. I have tried same for other formats like .tsx, .jsx, etc.

Absolute path does not work in require thus the relative path is provided.

The relative path is correctly provided.


I have also tried converting the variable to string like below but it didn't work.
const contentDynamic = require(`${new_path}`).Data;

How should I fix it? Is there anything i am missing in terms of principles and doing wrong? Please help me with the fix to this.
